# Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to build a gridview with several columns in it. But I'm facing this error "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening. I tried changing the syntax of Eval("pid") to (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"pid")) but to no avail. What I might be missing?
Here is my aspx code for one column from several other columns.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    ShowFooter="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                    DataKeyNames="pid"
                    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
                    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
                    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
                    OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
                    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="30"
                    Width="100%" AllowSorting="True"
                    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">    

                    <Columns>                           
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Number" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                            <ItemTemplate>                          
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPID" Text='<%# Eval("pid")  %>' Width="130px" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="txtProjectNumber" Text='<%# Eval("pid") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("pid") %>' Width="130px" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>                               
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Any help is highly appreciated as I'm stuck on this problem from long time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only assume your tags or something else is messed up. As noted, %# works inside of gridview, listview and even repeater. So, the above markup must not be inside of a gridview then? You have to post more of the gridview markup, but that markup has to be inside of the gv

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal The markup shown here is inside the gridview itself. Adding more makupfor clarity..